# Are there any good websites on which to teach yourself to read sheet music?

Tags: sheet-music, practice, flute, lessons

My question is simple: Are there any reputable websites that I could use to learn/teach myself how to properly read sheet music?

I have in my search come across a few that seemed *OK*, but they came across as having very little effort put into their curriculum, leaving the student to Google most of the terminology. The site I am currently using does not even have a single YouTube video or anything of the sort to explain the basics, so I have effectively hit a dead end and could really use some help.

Thank you in advance.